# Convert xml to key-value pair notation

Tags: xml, key-value, xmlstarlet

I use `xmlstarlet el -v` to display the structure of an xml file, including all the attributes and values. I would like to convert its output to some sort of key-value pairs, i.e. each attribute with its value on a separate line (including the XPath); each line must be unique.

```xml
<?xml version=1.0 encoding=UTF-8?>
<topRoot>
  <topSystem>
    <commSvcEp>
      <commSyslog descr="Syslog Service" name="syslog" policyOwner="local" severity="critical">
        <commSyslogClient adminState="disabled" forwardingFacility="local7" hostname="none" name="secondary" severity="critical"></commSyslogClient>
        <commSyslogClient adminState="disabled" forwardingFacility="local7" hostname="none" name="tertiary" severity="critical"></commSyslogClient>
        <commSyslogClient adminState="disabled" forwardingFacility="local7" hostname="none" name="primary" severity="critical"></commSyslogClient>
      </commSyslog>
    </commSvcEp>
  </topSystem>
</topRoot>
```

Current result:

```
topRoot/topSystem/commSvcEp/commSyslog[@descr='Syslog Service' and @name='syslog' and @policyOwner='local' and @severity='critical']
topRoot/topSystem/commSvcEp/commSyslog/commSyslogClient[@adminState='disabled' and @forwardingFacility='local7' and @hostname='none' and @name='secondary' and @severity='critical']
topRoot/topSystem/commSvcEp/commSyslog/commSyslogClient[@adminState='disabled' and @forwardingFacility='local7' and @hostname='none' and @name='tertiary' and @severity='critical']
topRoot/topSystem/commSvcEp/commSyslog/commSyslogClient[@adminState='disabled' and @forwardingFacility='local7' and @hostname='none' and @name='primary' and @severity='critical']
```

Desired result (could be anything similar; the indices are just an idea):

```
topRoot/topSystem/commSvcEp/commSyslog@descr='Syslog Service'
topRoot/topSystem/commSvcEp/commSyslog@name='syslog'
topRoot/topSystem/commSvcEp/commSyslog@policyOwner='local'
topRoot/topSystem/commSvcEp/commSyslog@severity='critical'
topRoot/topSystem/commSvcEp/commSyslog/commSyslogClient[0]@adminState='disabled'
topRoot/topSystem/commSvcEp/commSyslog/commSyslogClient[0]@forwardingFacility='local7'
topRoot/topSystem/commSvcEp/commSyslog/commSyslogClient[0]@hostname='none'
topRoot/topSystem/commSvcEp/commSyslog/commSyslogClient[0]@name='secondary'
topRoot/topSystem/commSvcEp/commSyslog/commSyslogClient[0]@severity='critical'
topRoot/topSystem/commSvcEp/commSyslog/commSyslogClient[1]@adminState='disabled'
topRoot/topSystem/commSvcEp/commSyslog/commSyslogClient[1]@forwardingFacility='local7'
topRoot/topSystem/commSvcEp/commSyslog/commSyslogClient[1]@hostname='none'
topRoot/topSystem/commSvcEp/commSyslog/commSyslogClient[1]@name='tertiary'
topRoot/topSystem/commSvcEp/commSyslog/commSyslogClient[1]@severity='critical'
topRoot/topSystem/commSvcEp/commSyslog/commSyslogClient[2]@adminState='disabled'
topRoot/topSystem/commSvcEp/commSyslog/commSyslogClient[2]@forwardingFacility='local7'
topRoot/topSystem/commSvcEp/commSyslog/commSyslogClient[2]@hostname='none'
topRoot/topSystem/commSvcEp/commSyslog/commSyslogClient[2]@name='primary'
topRoot/topSystem/commSvcEp/commSyslog/commSyslogClient[2]@severity='critical'
```

What I'm trying to accomplish, is being able to run `diff` over two such files or using `grep` to filter matching patterns. I'm sure there's a way to create such output, without using `sed`, `awk` or anything else but `xmlstarlet` itself.

I'm pretty much a newbie regarding xmlstarlet and the whole xml world (not only by the fact that I dislike xml due to its complexity and parsing overhead, etc), so I'd really appreciate your help. Thanks!

Comment: Could you please paste the XML or a part of it?

Comment: Here you go: http://sprunge.us/RbhI (it's only a fragment of a huge xml document)

Comment: "I'm sure there's a way to create such output, without using `sed`, `awk` or anything else but `xmlstarlet` itself." - Unless you're planning to hack on `xmlstarlet`'s code, I don't think so. If you can assume that the attribute values have no spaces in them, `awk` seems like a good choice.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Since you're already using `xmlstarlet`, you could also use XSLT.

**XSLT 1.0** (can be run with xmlstarlet by using the `tr` command)

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="text"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:param name="sep" select="'.'"/>

    <xsl:template match="text()"/>

    <xsl:template match="*">
        <xsl:variable name="path">
            <xsl:for-each select="ancestor-or-self::*">
                <xsl:variable name="predicate">
                    <xsl:call-template name="genPredicate"/>
                </xsl:variable>
                <xsl:if test="ancestor::*">
                    <xsl:value-of select="$sep"/>
                </xsl:if>
                <xsl:value-of select="concat(local-name(),$predicate)"/>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </xsl:variable>
        <xsl:for-each select="@*">
            <xsl:value-of select="concat($path,$sep,name(),'=',.)"/>
            <xsl:text>&#xA;</xsl:text>
        </xsl:for-each>
        <xsl:if test="not(@*)">
            <xsl:text>&#xA;</xsl:text>          
        </xsl:if>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="node()"/>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template name="genPredicate">
        <xsl:if test="preceding-sibling::*[local-name()=local-name(current())] or following-sibling::*[local-name()=local-name(current())]">
            <xsl:value-of select="concat('[',count(preceding-sibling::*[local-name()=local-name(current())])+1,']')"/>          
        </xsl:if>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Note: There is a parameter named `sep` so you can change the separator from the command line (using `-p sep="/"` or whatever separator you want). It's currently set to your preferred ".".

**Output**

```
commSyslog.descr=Syslog Service
commSyslog.name=syslog
commSyslog.policyOwner=local
commSyslog.severity=critical
commSyslog.commSyslogClient[1].adminState=disabled
commSyslog.commSyslogClient[1].forwardingFacility=local7
commSyslog.commSyslogClient[1].hostname=none
commSyslog.commSyslogClient[1].name=secondary
commSyslog.commSyslogClient[1].severity=critical
commSyslog.commSyslogClient[2].adminState=disabled
commSyslog.commSyslogClient[2].forwardingFacility=local7
commSyslog.commSyslogClient[2].hostname=none
commSyslog.commSyslogClient[2].name=tertiary
commSyslog.commSyslogClient[2].severity=critical
commSyslog.commSyslogClient[3].adminState=disabled
commSyslog.commSyslogClient[3].forwardingFacility=local7
commSyslog.commSyslogClient[3].hostname=none
commSyslog.commSyslogClient[3].name=primary
commSyslog.commSyslogClient[3].severity=critical
commSyslog.commSyslogMonitor.adminState=disabled
commSyslog.commSyslogMonitor.descr=
commSyslog.commSyslogMonitor.name=
commSyslog.commSyslogMonitor.severity=critical
commSyslog.commSyslogConsole.adminState=disabled
commSyslog.commSyslogConsole.descr=
commSyslog.commSyslogConsole.name=
commSyslog.commSyslogConsole.severity=critical
commSyslog.commSyslogSource.audits=disabled
commSyslog.commSyslogSource.descr=
commSyslog.commSyslogSource.events=disabled
commSyslog.commSyslogSource.faults=enabled
commSyslog.commSyslogSource.name=
commSyslog.commSyslogFile.adminState=enabled
commSyslog.commSyslogFile.descr=
commSyslog.commSyslogFile.name=messages
commSyslog.commSyslogFile.severity=critical
commSyslog.commSyslogFile.size=4194304
```

Comment: That's amazing, how did manage to write the XSLT? Seems really tough! Thanks a lot for your solution.

Comment: @watain - You're very welcome. It was pretty easy actually. I had already written the XSLT to output xpath's for every element, so I just needed to modify it to match your output (like stripping the leading "/", attributes, and only outputting the predicate if there was a preceding/following sibling). It looks more complicated than it is :-)

Comment: I tried your XSLT using `xmlstarlet tr trans.xslt test.xml`, but I get the following errors: `compilation error: file xmlkv.xslt line 4 element parameter
 xsltStylePreCompute: unknown xsl:parameter
 compilation error: file xmlkv.xslt line 4 element parameter
 xsltParseStylesheetTop: unknown parameter element`

Do I need to add some more options to xmlstarlet in order for it to work?

Comment: @watain - OOPS! I had `xsl:parameter` when it should've been `xsl:param`. Sorry about that! I edited my answer.

Answer (score 1):

I decided to write a small program using libxml2, which parses the XML and recursively outputs it in the desired format.

The code can be compiled using the following command, or something similar (I decided to call it xmlkv, *kv* standing for key-value):

```
cc -o xmlkv xmlkv.c -s -Os -Wall -Wextra `xml2-config --cflags --libs`
```

The code:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <libxml/parser.h>
#include <libxml/tree.h>

static void print_elements(xmlNode *);

static void
print_elements(xmlNode *node)
{
    xmlNode *n;
    xmlAttrPtr a;
    xmlChar *v, *p, *q;

    for (n = node; n; n = n->next) {
        if (n->type == XML_ELEMENT_NODE) {
            if ((p = xmlGetNodePath(n)) == NULL)
                return;

            for (q = p; *q; q++)
                if (*q == '/')
                    *q = '.';

            for (a = n->properties; a; a = a->next) {
                if ((v = xmlGetProp(n, a->name)) == NULL)
                    return;

                printf("%s.%s=%s\n", p + 1, a->name, v);
                xmlFree(v);
            }

            xmlFree(p);
        }

        print_elements(n->children);
    }
}

int
main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    xmlDoc *doc = NULL;
    xmlNode *root = NULL;

    LIBXML_TEST_VERSION

    if (argc != 2) {
        fprintf(stderr, "usage: %s <file>\n", *argv);
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    if ((doc = xmlReadFile(argv[1], NULL, 0)) == NULL)
        return EXIT_FAILURE;

    if ((root = xmlDocGetRootElement(doc)) == NULL)
        return EXIT_FAILURE;

    print_elements(root);

    xmlFreeDoc(doc);
    xmlCleanupParser();

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

A test:

```
$ cat test.xml
<commSyslog descr="Syslog Service" name="syslog" policyOwner="local" severity="critical">
<commSyslogClient adminState="disabled" forwardingFacility="local7" hostname="none" name="secondary" severity="critical"/>
<commSyslogClient adminState="disabled" forwardingFacility="local7" hostname="none" name="tertiary" severity="critical"/>
<commSyslogClient adminState="disabled" forwardingFacility="local7" hostname="none" name="primary" severity="critical"/>
<commSyslogMonitor adminState="disabled" descr="" name="" severity="critical"/>
<commSyslogConsole adminState="disabled" descr="" name="" severity="critical"/>
<commSyslogSource audits="disabled" descr="" events="disabled" faults="enabled" name=""/>
<commSyslogFile adminState="enabled" descr="" name="messages" severity="critical" size="4194304"/>
</commSyslog>

$ ./xmlkv test.xml
commSyslog.descr=Syslog Service
commSyslog.name=syslog
commSyslog.policyOwner=local
commSyslog.severity=critical
commSyslog.commSyslogClient[1].adminState=disabled
commSyslog.commSyslogClient[1].forwardingFacility=local7
commSyslog.commSyslogClient[1].hostname=none
commSyslog.commSyslogClient[1].name=secondary
commSyslog.commSyslogClient[1].severity=critical
commSyslog.commSyslogClient[2].adminState=disabled
commSyslog.commSyslogClient[2].forwardingFacility=local7
commSyslog.commSyslogClient[2].hostname=none
commSyslog.commSyslogClient[2].name=tertiary
commSyslog.commSyslogClient[2].severity=critical
commSyslog.commSyslogClient[3].adminState=disabled
commSyslog.commSyslogClient[3].forwardingFacility=local7
commSyslog.commSyslogClient[3].hostname=none
commSyslog.commSyslogClient[3].name=primary
commSyslog.commSyslogClient[3].severity=critical
commSyslog.commSyslogMonitor.adminState=disabled
commSyslog.commSyslogMonitor.descr=
commSyslog.commSyslogMonitor.name=
commSyslog.commSyslogMonitor.severity=critical
commSyslog.commSyslogConsole.adminState=disabled
commSyslog.commSyslogConsole.descr=
commSyslog.commSyslogConsole.name=
commSyslog.commSyslogConsole.severity=critical
commSyslog.commSyslogSource.audits=disabled
commSyslog.commSyslogSource.descr=
commSyslog.commSyslogSource.events=disabled
commSyslog.commSyslogSource.faults=enabled
commSyslog.commSyslogSource.name=
commSyslog.commSyslogFile.adminState=enabled
commSyslog.commSyslogFile.descr=
commSyslog.commSyslogFile.name=messages
commSyslog.commSyslogFile.severity=critical
commSyslog.commSyslogFile.size=4194304
```

Seems nice, just what I wanted. Of course, replacing `/` with `.` is pretty much useless, but I prefer this notation since it's better on the eyes.

Comment: Cool program. Can't get it to compile on my Fedora 18 box.

Comment: Have used compile flags as given  .... 
cc -o xmlkv xmlkv.c -s -static -Os -Wall -Wextra `xml2-config --cflags --libs`  .... but get compile error .... /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lxml2
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lz
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status .... weird because I have installed zlib-devel, libxml2, libxml2-devel

Comment: Scratch that, figured out correct compile flags from https://github.com/ApOgEE/mingw-libxml2-example/blob/master/keyword-example/Makefile

Comment: @BryanHunt I guess by just removing the `-static` flag it would've worked for you (I'm pretty sure the static libraries for libxml2 and zlib aren't installed on your system).

Comment: Thx, I'm a bit of noob when it comes to gcc linker.

Answer (score 0):

[yq](https://mikefarah.gitbook.io/yq/) can be used to convert XML to properties and vice versa.

```xml
<?xml version=1.0 encoding=UTF-8?>
<topRoot>
  <topSystem>
    <commSvcEp>
      <commSyslog descr="Syslog Service" name="syslog" policyOwner="local" severity="critical">
        <commSyslogClient adminState="disabled" forwardingFacility="local7" hostname="none" name="secondary" severity="critical"></commSyslogClient>
        <commSyslogClient adminState="disabled" forwardingFacility="local7" hostname="none" name="tertiary" severity="critical"></commSyslogClient>
        <commSyslogClient adminState="disabled" forwardingFacility="local7" hostname="none" name="primary" severity="critical"></commSyslogClient>
      </commSyslog>
    </commSvcEp>
  </topSystem>
</topRoot>
```

Convert XML to properties:

```bash
yq --input-format xml --output-format props
```

**Output**

```
+p_xml = version=1.0 encoding=UTF-8
topRoot.topSystem.commSvcEp.commSyslog.+@descr = Syslog Service
topRoot.topSystem.commSvcEp.commSyslog.+@name = syslog
topRoot.topSystem.commSvcEp.commSyslog.+@policyOwner = local
topRoot.topSystem.commSvcEp.commSyslog.+@severity = critical
topRoot.topSystem.commSvcEp.commSyslog.commSyslogClient.0.+@adminState = disabled
topRoot.topSystem.commSvcEp.commSyslog.commSyslogClient.0.+@forwardingFacility = local7
topRoot.topSystem.commSvcEp.commSyslog.commSyslogClient.0.+@hostname = none
topRoot.topSystem.commSvcEp.commSyslog.commSyslogClient.0.+@name = secondary
topRoot.topSystem.commSvcEp.commSyslog.commSyslogClient.0.+@severity = critical
topRoot.topSystem.commSvcEp.commSyslog.commSyslogClient.1.+@adminState = disabled
topRoot.topSystem.commSvcEp.commSyslog.commSyslogClient.1.+@forwardingFacility = local7
topRoot.topSystem.commSvcEp.commSyslog.commSyslogClient.1.+@hostname = none
topRoot.topSystem.commSvcEp.commSyslog.commSyslogClient.1.+@name = tertiary
topRoot.topSystem.commSvcEp.commSyslog.commSyslogClient.1.+@severity = critical
topRoot.topSystem.commSvcEp.commSyslog.commSyslogClient.2.+@adminState = disabled
topRoot.topSystem.commSvcEp.commSyslog.commSyslogClient.2.+@forwardingFacility = local7
topRoot.topSystem.commSvcEp.commSyslog.commSyslogClient.2.+@hostname = none
topRoot.topSystem.commSvcEp.commSyslog.commSyslogClient.2.+@name = primary
topRoot.topSystem.commSvcEp.commSyslog.commSyslogClient.2.+@severity = critical
```

Convert properties back to the original XML:

```bash
yq --input-format props --output-format xml --indent 2
```